Raster to polygon in QGIS - How to Poligonize using a limit of vertices
In ArcGIS, when I use the Raster to Polygon tool, I can set the Maximum vertices per polygon feature parameter, where the algorithm subdivides a polygon into smaller polygons. For example:

The result of this process is shown below, where the attribute table contains a column called gridcode with the subdivision of the polygons.

My problem is that I'm looking for an alternative to do that in QGIS, but I couldn't find any options for this. Does anyone know of any tool or plugin in QGIS for polygonizing rasters that would allow me to limit the vertices for each feature?

There is no option for limiting the number of vertices in the QGIS Polygonize (raster to vector) tool, but you can post-process the layer with the Subdivide tool https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#subdivide.

Subdivides the geometry. The returned geometry will be a collection
containing subdivided parts from the original geometry, where no part
has more than the specified maximum number of nodes.
This is useful for dividing a complex geometry into less complex
parts, easier to spatially index and faster to perform spatial
operations. Curved geometries will be segmentized before subdivision.


Thanks for your answer. I will try to post-process the layer as you suggested among other alternatives I thought of here. I will post the results later to help others with the same problem.
